# How to lock result in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a formula that returns a value based on data in another worksheet. Obviously when I change the data, returned value will change. I would like to know if there is a way that I could lock the value in spite of data changes for some time (i.e. untill I fill another cell or tick a box etc) . I would like to be able to lock it and unlock at any time with some simple action. If my explanation is not clear please let me know.

Comment: There are only two ways I know of to "lock" a calculated cell: 1) Turn off automatic calculation (typically not recommended), or 2) convert the cell to a value (copy cell -> right-click -> paste-special -> values; note that this will remove the formula, so you may want to copy that to a different cell) and only put in the formula when you want it to update and then convert to value again.  Neither of these solutions is elegant.

Comment: Alternately you could use VBA to manage it for you, but then you have a .xlsm file which comes with its own set of problems if you're planning to distribute or share the workbook.

Comment: Option number 1 will not work for me because I need to lock only some of the cells, not the entire worksheet. Option number 2 solves the problem but manual copying every time would be troublesome for the number of formulas I have. Could you give me an example how to do it in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some very simple VBA that will apply a formula to a cell so that it performs the calculation, then sets the cell to the value which removes the formula.  This could be expanded for any number of cells (just need new With statements).  So when you want to update the cells, you would run the macro.

```
Sub UpdateCells()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .Formula = "Yourformulahere"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```