# Updating a Cell on a Certain Date and Locking in Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if there was a way to create a function for the following. I am trying to update a cell, say G3 with a value in D3 but I want to do it on a certain date. I want for that cell to update on that date and then lock in with the value.

For example, if D3 has a value of 30, I want for my G3 cell to update with 30 on 10/12/2012. After that date I want that value to lock in as the data in D3 will change over time. This formula would need to be copied as I am trying to find a trend detail on a weekly basis.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is fairly impossible to do with a formula. You can test for the date and update the value only on that date. But you cannot use a formula to replace itself with a permanent value received dynamically. This can be done with VBA however, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435922/how-to-lock-result-in-excel)

Comment: Better to use an Excel macro. If you want to use a formula: `=IF(TODAY()="10/12/2012", DO THIS, DO THAT)`. That formula will work during one year.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Why would the OP use an Excel macro for a Google Sheets Function?

Comment: I didn't notice that...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing this in [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), you can achieve this easily via a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). Specifically, with [atDate(year, month, day)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atdateyear,-month,-day) you can make a function run at a certain date. To do this, you would first have to create the trigger. You can do this manually from the script editor, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). You could also do this [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), by running a function that creates such trigger. The function would be, in this case:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("setAndLock")
  .timeBased()
  .atDate(2012, 12, 10)
  .create();
}
```

Running this function will create a trigger that will fire a function called `setAndLock` at date `2012/12/10`, which should copy the value from `D3` to `G3` and protect this last cell. Such a function could be similar to this one:

```
function setAndLock() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Copying the value from D3 to G3:
  var origin = sheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
  var dest = sheet.getRange("G3");
  dest.setValue(origin);
  // Protecting G3:
  var protection = dest.protect();
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

Please take into account that the cell cannot be locked from the current user nor the owner of the spreadsheet, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses).

I hope this is of any help.